Retrieve all items from a table column and auto update as data is added to table in Excel?
I have tried to use the formula from this similar question but cannot seem to get this working. It's also more complicated that what I want but closest I could find to my question.
Data (formatted as a table "TeamList")
Name         Emp#
Sally Doe    12345
John Doe     11234
John Doe     22345
James Doe    33456

Desired Result (on a different worksheet)
Emp#
12345
11234
22345
33456

The results (on a dashboard of sorts) would auto update as the source table is added to. I can index/match from there to gather the rest of the data, I just haven't been able to fill the Employee number from the table.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

for version 2021 or newer =TeamList[Emp'#] should do it.

Also, the question which you have listed, it says about returning unique values from two range, whereas yours is different, so both are actually different questions. Please refer to @gns100 already provided a solution which should work btw!

I apologize. Looking back at my question it was pretty ambiguous. The main machine I'm on is 2016, but looks like @gns100 provided the correct answer. So simple and can't believe I hadn't tried that before.
How should I close the question?
Thank you
